# RegDelete cannot delete Registry key in WSH 5.7

Tags: windows-vista, vbscript, registry, wsh

Based on the advice provided at http://www.tweakguides.com/VA_4.html to prevent Windows Vista from "intelligently" rearranging column formats in Windows Explorer, I have written a script to automate the process a little.

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


'Remove the "filthy" reg keys first.
regKey = "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\"


WScript.Echo "Deleting " & regKey & VbCrLf
WshShell.RegDelete regKey

regKey = "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\"

WScript.Echo "Deleting " & regKey & VbCrLf
WshShell.RegDelete regKey


'Then recreate a clean Bags key, with sub-keys and FolderType value.
regKey = "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\FolderType"

WScript.Echo "Creating " & regKey & " as 'NotSpecified' REG_SZ " & VbCrLf
WshShell.RegWrite regKey, "NotSpecified", "REG_SZ"

WScript.Echo "Now define the columns of your preference in Windows Explorer," & VbCrLf
WScript.Echo "and click the Apply to Folders button in Folder Options." & VbCrLf
```

But it is refusing to delete the registry key

```
E:\archive\settings\Windows Vista Explorer columns.vbs(9, 1) WshShell.RegDelete:
 Unable to remove registry key "HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Mi
crosoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\".
```

The suggestion is to put trailing "\" to indicate a key, which I did. Any ideas?

Comment: It may have to do with permissions, are you running as Administrator, and are those keys editable by that user/group?

Comment: Yes i am administrator, and yes i disable UAC all the time ;-)

Comment: Have you verified that you can delete the key manually via RegEdit?

Comment: Everything works the regular mousing way.

Answer (score 2):

Does your registry setting have subkeys? I think you have to delete those before you can delete the key.

Answer (score 1):

Disable UAC in Windows Vista, then this script will just work fine.

Comment: I never use UAC on any Win Vista/2008/7 machine ;-)

Answer (score 1):

break it dooown : )

```
Const HKCR=&H80000000:Const HKCU=&H80000001:Const HKLM=&H80000002:Const HKU=&H80000003:Const HKCC=&H80000005

dim pc,o,hive,key,name,value,i
pc="."
Set o=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & pc & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

hive=HKCU
key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers\knownfolders\0\windows wallpapers\mergefolders"
regrid 5

sub regrid(levels)
dim a,n,j,base,s
    a=split(key,"\")
    n=ubound(a)
    base="":for i=0 to levels-1:base=base & a(i) & "\":next
    for i=n to levels step -1
        s="":for j=levels to i:s=s & a(j) & "\":next
        o.DeleteKey hive,base & s
    next
end sub
```

thank you all for your support in liberating education